# Jprofiler 8.1 compatible with JDK 6

Tags: jprofiler

We are trying to start remote session. Our remote server is linux and trying connect to remote server.

When we try to install Jprofiler 8.1 its not supporting with JDK 6.1

What the compatible JDK for Jprofile 8.1.

Comment: either google it,or try with JDK7 or JDK8, shouldn't take more than 5 minutes!

Comment: Per the changelog (and in the first Google search result - https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/changelog.html), JDK7 & 8

Comment: @Tgsmith61591:  I don't see that being an absolute prohibition of support for Java 6; although I could understand it since not even Oracle supports it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The JProfiler 8.1 GUI needs a Java 7 or Java 8 JRE to run. For the profiled JVM, JProfiler supports Java 5 and higher.